# "Collision" vs "Crash" --- If a ship hits a bridge, is it a crash or a collision?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

**"Baltimore Key Bridge collapses after ship collision"** [CNN-Baltimore bridge collapse](https://edition.cnn.com/us/live-news/baltimore-bridge-collapse-03-26-24-intl-hnk/index.html)

The word "**collision"** has drawn my attention, because when I read it at first, it made me think the ship has collided with another ship, then it turned out that the ship has actually crashed into a bridge.

So, I looked it up again and [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/collide) says:

> *If two or more moving people or objects collide, they crash into one another. If a moving person or object collides with a person or object that is not moving, they crash into them.*

Also, the Cambridge dictionary says that **a collision** is:
*"an accident that happens when two vehicles hit each other with force."*

So, as far as I can understand, the word "collision" seems to require at least two moving objects, but in this one, there are not two moving objects. What actually happened is that **a moving object(the ship)** has crashed into **the bridge(non-moving object.)**

If dictionaries are right, is the word "collision" the correct word linguistically?

Comment: The ship collided with the bridge or the ship crashed into the bridge. It is not wrong. MW: The meaning of COLLIDE is to come together with solid or direct impact. This is just a non-issue. Insurance companies issue collision reports, for example. What I mean is collide, collision is more formal than crash.

Comment: As just a minor note, I would tend to say that "collision" can cover a wider gamut of incidents than "crash". To me "crash" tends to indicate total (or at least significant) damage to whatever is under discussion, but "collision" can be anything from not even leaving a scratch to total loss.

Comment: In nautical terms it's an allision, but that isn't used at all in everyday speech. https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/allision

Comment: The Collins quote says that both collision scenarios are crashes. Anyway, the ship didn't crash into the bridge pier: it drifted into the pier as a result of power loss. Collision is the more appropriate term.

Comment: I wouldn't say of the bridge, though, that it had collided with a ship.

Comment: @WeatherVane, When you read the headline, didn't you think there were two ships which crashed into one another?

Comment: People have died and you're trying to accuse CNN of a non-existent error. Maybe get some sense of propriety?

Comment: @Yunus no, I didn't think that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It normally is the user's choice; either *crash* or *collision* are appropriate.

However, I've worked for a government agency which had their own "style book": airplanes *crashed*, automotive vehicles *collided* in *accidents*. So *where* the language is applied has an impact (oops).

Comment: Presumably if one plane hit another in the air, that would be a collision. Although a surface vehicle can collide with a fixed object, it would sound odd to speak of a plane 'colliding' with the ground, so I suppose that's why the less formal term 'crash' was preferred.

Comment: @KateBunting, at that agency, a mid-air collision would have been termed a "crash" (and eventually, it *would* be -- what goes up comes down). As for planes colliding on the tarmac, I'll leave that to the said agency to describe. ;-)

Comment: Weird that your style guide mandated the word *accident*. Many people these days are actively discouraging calling car crashes "accidents", as it downplays the culpability in poor or distracted driving. Most car crashes are not really "accidents".